# Alias for long lookups

Tags: c#, alias

I am working on a project that has nested Lists of classes. hence my code look like this when I want to get a variable.

```
MainClass.subclass1[element1].subClass2[element2].subClass3[element3].value;
```

I was wondering how I could get an alias for subClass3 so I can get all the variables in it without having to look in all the subclasses, like this.

```
subClass3Alias.value
```

in c++ this would be easy simply have a pointer pointing to it, but C# does not really have pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for pointers – types in C# are usually [reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057267/1968) anyway, meaning that you can just copy them and they will refer to the original object (like pointers in C++):

```
var subclassAlias = MainClass.subclass1[element1].subClass2[element2].subClass3[element3];
```

Now you can use `subclassAlias.value`.

A slightly different thing occurs if your type happens to be a value type: in that case, the above will still work – but `subclassAlias` will be a *value copy* of the original value, meaning that changes to `subclassAlias` will not be reflected in the original object.

That said, this looks like suspicious code anyway – normally such deep levels of nesting are a sign of bad design and violate the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

(Incidentally, in C++ you wouldn’t use pointers either.)

Comment: It would be a variable containing a reference (most likely), aka a pointer.

Comment: It's probably best to use the proper terms to avoid confusion later. In C#, a pointer is rarely used, and is something different. A C# reference value functions much like a C++ pointer value, though.